# Simple collision resolution in a platformer game

Tags: physics, collision-resolution, platformer

[image]

I want to make a 2d platformer with moving, jumping and wall sliding. How can I make a simple pleasant collision resolution system that works for the following rectangles.

Player is red, platform is black, I want to detect if the player is sliding a wall, or hitting the ground, or doing both ( as in third example). Also take the appropriate response.

Also I have no idea what I am talking about so a little context might help.

These resources helped me:

How to resolve collision:
[2D AABBs and resolving multiple collisions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69339/2d-aabbs-and-resolving-multiple-collisions)

[How to detect overlap between aabb vs aabb](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-basics-and-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6331#:%7E:text=Collision%20resolution%20is%20the%20act,allow%20them%20to%20remain%20intersecting.&text=The%20idea%20behind%20impulse%20resolution,to%20separate%20objects%20found%20colliding.):

http://noonat.github.io/intersect/

Comment: Presumably you started by typing "platformer collision detection" into your favourite search engine, and found the many existing guides, tutorials, examples, and past Q&A on this topic. After reviewing this wealth of resources, which guide have you chosen to try to follow? How have you tried putting it into practice so far, and where did you get stuck along the way?

Comment: Looks like you found a great set of resources there. What's the next step you need help with after putting those into practice? Or, if you've solved your problem, would you like to post your solution as an answer below?